# Import from other files in GTK

Tags: python, gtk, gnome-builder

I'm creating a new project on gnome-builder. The trouble is I have a list in file vaccine.py and now I want to import it into my window.py file but when I run the program it shows "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'vaccine'". I try to create a test python file and import that list and no error occurs. Can someone show me what I do wrong?

[image: 1]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have to add your new file to the meson.build file. As you develop in a flatpak environment your file will not be automatically packaged into this environment. In order to do that this template uses a meson buildsystem. A note: GNOME Builder always installs applications as this resolves missing icons/settings etc.

Comment: Tks I find the same solution here: https://discourse.gnome.org/t/builder-python-gtk-error-with-importing-modules/1535
I have another question about adding python libraries to flatpak environment here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70358727/add-matplotlib-and-numpy-to-flatpak-gnome-builder-project. Could you check it out please? Tks a lot